# How do I create a windows server vm on existing linux server running cPanel?

Tags: windows, vmware, alma-linux, cpanel, asp.net

I have a web server running Almalinux and cPanel (LAMP Stack).

We need to run a new web app created with ASP.net and SQL Server on the same server and according to our research, there is no way to do that from inside cPanel or WHM.

So, we have been considering creating a Windows Server VM for that purpose.

Based on the above, I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to achieve this setup using standard vmware software, or does it require any special tools or considerations?
2. Will this be optimal for the situation described, or am I missing something or better options?

Comment: well, technically both the .NET platform and sqlserver are available for Linux, but whether getting your specific application to run is worth the effort is questionable.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am concerned about the overall performance of the app ... I have had bad experiences before running PHP apps on IIS and Windows so, I am assuming the opposite would be the same

Comment: Would be less worried about that – but about the very real risk that it would simply need *a lot* of work. It really depends on what your long term plans with the application are. I'd say, the Windows VM approach is the more sensible one in the near and medium term.